# How can I do this in xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When the user click on a text, the text color and its background color must be changed!

Note that there are two recyclerViews.

I tried to use a selector with (android:state_focused="true"), but when I click on a text from the second recyclerView, the focus disappears form the first one!

**The application is in Arabic language**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please refer this link: https://github.com/fiskurgit/ChipCloud

Comment: @osama astal Can you tell please if te response help you?..

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you can use ChipGroup and Chip ( https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/ )
And change the color when chip are selected

For ChipGroup and add Chip inside in XML :

```
         <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:id="@+id/chipGroupOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                      <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                        android:id="@+id/chip"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

In code, add chip in group like that :

```
                ChipGroup chipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chipGroupOne);
                Chip chip = new Chip(getContext());
                chip.setId(id);
                chip.setText("text");
                chip.setCheckable(true);
                chipGroup.addView(chip);
```

For change color how you want, you need to change chip style attribute with custom style  like

style.xml

```
<style name="CustomChip" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chip_state</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_chip</item>
</style>
```

text_color_chip.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
       android:color="@color/primaryColorCheck" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"
       android:color="@color/primaryColorUncheck" />
</selector>
```

chip_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@color/colorSecondaryLight" android:state_checked="true" />
   <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</selector>
```

And apply style like that in XML with adding this attribute in to chip

```
    style="@style/CustomChip"
```

If you want apply style programmaticaly to chip, you need to apply a new ChipDrawable  who contain the style to Chip, like that :

chip.xml

```
<chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   style="@style/CustomChip"
/>
```

and apply like that in code

```
                    chip.setChipDrawable(ChipDrawable.createFromResource(getContext(), R.xml.chip));
```

I hope I could help you